# Import Securty Groups to Nest using PowerShell (Add-ADGroupMember)

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I have +100 rows of AD Security Groups of which each collection might contain 3-7 Security Groups that need to be added as members.

I have this data broken down in a CSV, but so far I've been unable to utilize the Import-CSV cmdlet to work with the data.

Thus far, I have simply created +100 entries as outlined below, but I would like to see how I might be able to address this by importing the CSV.

I've been reading through other CSV questions on here and re-read some of my powershell books, but nothing so far that would result in a proper solution.

```
$DCName = DC01
Add-ADGroupMember -Server $DCName -MainGroup -Members 'Group001', 'Group002', 'Group003' 
Add-ADGroupMember -Server $DCName -SecondGroup -Members 'Group011', 'Group022', 'Group033'
Add-ADGroupMember -Server $DCName -ThirdGroup -Members 'Group111', 'Group222'
```

Inside the CSV:

```
MainGroup   SecondGroup   ThirdGroup
Group001    Group011      Group111
Group002    Group022      Group222
Group003    Group033
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Are there two CSVs? If not then for the example you have given how and what elements the first row in csv is linked to?

Comment: @AmanSharma there's only 1 CSV. Using the CSV example above, cell A1 would be MainGroup, A2 would be Group002, and A3 would be Group003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There isn't a property called `-MainGroup` in `Add-ADGroupMember`, you need to use `-Identity "MainGroup"`.
2. This isn't a good CSV-file. A row in a CSV-file should represent a single item and each columns should be an attribute that "describes" that item. Your column-values are independent from the others values on the same row. I would have written it like this:

   MembersToAdd.csv

   ```
   Group,Member
   MainGroup,Group001
   MainGroup,Group002
   SecondGroup,Group011
   SecondGroup,Group022
   ```

   That way you would have 1 row per task so it's clear who should be added where. Ex.

   ```
   Import-CSV MembersToAdd.csv | Foreach-Object {
       Write-Host "Add $($_.Member) to $($_.Group)"
       Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.Group -Members $_.Member

       #Or you could have added all members to an array, used `Group-Object Group` or 
       #something else to collect all members an do a single `Add-ADGroupMember` call for that group.
   }
   ```

However, to use the current CSV, you could try something like this:

```
$DCName = "DC01"

#Hashtable to store group = members values
$AddMembers = @{}

Import-CSV -Path mygrouplist.csv | ForEach-Object {
    #Foreach property (column)
    $_.psobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {

        #If property has value
        if($_.Value) {

            #If new "maingroup", create hashtable entry with an array to store values in
            if($AddMembers.ContainsKey($_.Name) -eq $false) { $AddMembers.Add($_.Name,@()) }

            #Add member to group in hashtable
            $AddMembers[$_.Name] += $_.Value
        }
    }
}

#Foreach entry (group) in hashtable, add members
$AddMembers.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Server $DCName -Identity $_.Name -Members $_.Value }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different takes on how to do this. The current format in the CSV file isnt very easy to use. I would recommend that you format the data before using it.

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
MainGroup                      Group002
ChildGroups                    {Group022, Group222}
```

You can either validate the childgroups and use multiple members when using `Add-ADGroupMember`. Or you can just loop through them.

```
$csvfile = Import-Csv csv.csv
foreach ($group in $csvfile)
{
    $group | Out-Host
    $formated = @{
        MainGroup = $group.MainGroup
        ChildGroups = ($group.secondgroup, $group.thirdgroup)

    }
    $formated | Out-Host #Formated hash table
    foreach ($group in $formated)
    {
        $maingroup = $group.Maingroup
        $childgroup = $group.childgroups
        Write-Host "Main: $maingroup"
        Write-Host "Child: $childgroup"
        Add-ADGroupMember -identity $maingroup -Members $childgroup

    }
}
```